# Is there a name for this type of graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

From a graph G I want to construct a graph (lets call it) G# with the following properties:

- Each node and each edge of G is a node of G#
- For each e in G connecting the nodes n1, n2 there exist the edges connecting e,n1 and e,n2
- no other edges exist in G#

G# is then bipartite with the nodes and edges of G being it's disjoint sets´. [It's like creating the line graph of G and stopping after the creation of the "new nodes"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph#Example).

Is there a name for this special kind of graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called the *[(first) barycentric subdivision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_%28graph_theory%29#Barycentric_Subdivisions)* of the graph.

Comment: That's a good observation. Of course, instead of constructing a new graph, it can be obtained from the original by subdividing the edges.

Comment: Exactly looking for this. Now the baby has a name I can more efficiently search for existing program modules fulfilling my need

Answer (score 1):

This is more like the [Total Graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotalGraph.html) than the Line Graph (because the nodes of $G\#$ consist of both the nodes and the edges of $G$), except that adjacency in $G\#$ is determined
only by *incidence* in $G$, rather than both incidence and adjacency in $G$ (which is the case in Line Graphs).

This is called the [Incidence Graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncidenceGraph.html) in configurations, though it doesn't seem to be popular in graph theory itself. As you correctly said, it is a bipartite graph.